# K8S (minikube) роутинг

Tags: nginx, devops, kubernetes, pod

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, для того что бы настроить роутинг в k8s.

Задачка:

Есть ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "4m"
    nginx.org/proxy-max-temp-file-size: "20480m"
    nginx.org/proxy-pass-headers: "X-Real-IP,X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Forwarded-Host,X-Forwarded-Port"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

spec:
  rules:
    - host: domain.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /mails
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              serviceName: ms-mails-web-service
              servicePort: 9500
```

В сервиса ms-mails-web-service есть 2 роута:

- [GET] /mails
- [POST] /mails/verify

нужно настроить роутинг так, что бы запросы шли на /mails и /mails/verify. Пока работает так:

**domain.local/mails и domain.local/mails/verify отдают страницу /mails**, а должны быть разные.

В NGINX такую задачу решал конфигом

```
location ~^/mails {
    try_files $uri @msMails;
}

location @msMails {
    proxy_pass http://some-ip:9002;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_body $request_body;
}
```

- p.s. **Нужно реализовать роутинг для api, проксировать body (post, PUT, PATCH запросы).**
- p.p.s. Искал в документации proxy_pass как в nginx, но так ничего и не понял.
- p.p.p.s. Готовых решений не прошу, буду рад просто ссылке на доку))
- p.p.p.p.s. я не DevOps, просто интересно потыкать k8s))

Comment: **pathType: Exact** означает точное совпадение роута. Изменил на **pathType: Prefix** - ничего не изменилось в плане работы ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить конфиг ingress:

```
- path: /mails
```

на

```
- path: mails(.*)
```

тогда, при запросе **domain/mails** на поде будет

```
 "REQUEST_URI" => "/"
```

а при запросе **domain/mails/verify**

```
"REQUEST_URI" => "//verify"
```

источник: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite

так же там есть **(/|$)** пока не совсем понимаю зачем это.

И не нравиться что `"REQUEST_URI" => "//verify"` ,а не `"REQUEST_URI" => "/verify"`

Answer (score 0):

заменяем

```
 `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1`
```

на

```
 `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`
```

потом `- path: mails(.*)` на `- path: mails(/|$)(.*)`

тогда `"REQUEST_URI" => "//verify"` измениться на `"REQUEST_URI" => "/verify"`